# Sub folder in Git project?

Tags: git, github, clone

I have been using Subversion for a long time and now I have switched to Git.

Now I need to know how to get sub folders in my Git project?

I know sombody will make 2 projects for this but I dont need 2 projects for this. I need to clone a subfolder and not my main project.

I use github.com.

Comment: Sorry but your question is very difficult to understand. What does "get sub folders" mean? create? What do you call "project"?

Comment: Git Tracks the root and all its sub folders by default, you dont have to do anything special

Comment: I wonder if this is what you were originally asking about: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer: http://blog.quilitz.de/2010/03/checkout-sub-directories-in-git-sparse-checkouts/

I had git 1.5.5, and it requires 1.7+; now I have 1.7 and it's all working fine. :) But thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you think it does - sure, you're only checking out some of the content, but your repository still contains all of the information for the entire project.

Comment: Yeah that will not do what you want. What you asked for is impossible in git.

Answer (score 6):

When cloning a git repository you always clone the whole repository.

If you want subfolders in your project simply create them though. As soon as you add files inside them (git only tracks files no folders -> if a folder is empty you cannot add it to your repo), they can be committed to your repository by committing the files inside.

Answer (score 3):

1. create a folder
2. "git add" this folder
3. "git commit -m 'message'"
4. "git push"

DONE!

Comment: git add in that case will give a message like `"fatal: Not a git repository: .../<subfolder name>"`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can! Github also provides SVN access for repositories. For example I want to get Android fonts here:
**https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/data/fonts**
Just run this command, see the pattern, replace /tree/master with /trunk:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/trunk/data/fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to add an empty folder. Create a file first, add a folder inside it and then link the file inside the folder. Similarly, once you have a main folder, you can add files or create subfolders inside this folder.